# Codeigniter Jquery And Upload

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

How to get <canvas> value and upload with codeigniter?

```
<div id="shirtDiv" class="page" style="width: 530px; height: 630px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <img id="tshirtFacing" src="<?=Base_url()?>assets/assetsCustom/img/crew_front.png"></img>
    <div id="drawingArea" style="position: absolute;top: 100px;left: 160px;z-index: 10;width: 200px;height: 400px;">
        <canvas id="tcanvas" width=200 height="400" class="hover" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var FormDataLogo = new FormData();
        $.each($("#tshirtFacing")[0].files, function (I, File) {
            FormDataLogo.append("tshirtFacing", File);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            data: FormDataLogo,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
            }
        })
```